# What was the first version of Android to use OpenSSL (and what version was it)? What was used prior?

Tags: tls, openssl, android, java, sslstrip

Android 1.6 source is the earliest I can find that references openssl 
(i.e., has OPENSSL_VERSION[_TEXT] defined

The script I ran to get these versions was:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl && cd openssl
$ for ANDROID_TAG in $(git ls-remote --tags| colrm 1 48| grep -v "\^{}"); do git checkout "$ANDROID_TAG"; OPENSSL_V="$(cat openssl.version)"; [[ -z $OPENSSL_V ]] && OPENSSL_V="$(grep OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT include/openssl/opensslv.h)"; echo "[$OPENSSL_V] - [$ANDROID_TAG]" >> openssl.versions; done
```

However, if you check the tags in that Git repo, there appears to be nothing earlier than 1.6. The [Where and how can I find and download Android 1.5 soure code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164864/where-and-how-can-i-find-and-download-android-1-5-source-code) question on SO has broken links to 1.5 source, and though I was able to find the [Java sources](http://rgruet.free.fr/public/android-1.5-cupcake-src.zip), but not the entire platform there I'm unable to look at the version.

So, my questions: What was the first version of Android to use OpenSSL? Was it used since 1.1? If so, what version? If not, what else did they use?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, OpenSSL libs were part of "external" from day one. At least, I remember it in the not-yet-opensource 0.9 tree *circa* 2008. I am sorry to confess, I don't remember which version of OpenSSL was included there. All I know, it was not upgraded for a long time.